# How to get specific strings from NSString?

Tags: ios, objective-c, search, nsstring, nsarray

I have a string such as:

> Sodium Nitrite **E250** is a food additive that gives cured meats,
>   such as ham **E103**, bacon, hot dogs, frankfurters, smoked fish
>   **E1255** corned beef, their characteristic red colour and flavour.

I need to get an NSArray of elements: **E250**, **E103**, **E1255** from text above and compare with my predefined NSArray(E100, E101,...E1500) elements
Is there any way how to do this?

Comment: Are you looking for all strings with a certain format?  Or just the three you stated?

Comment: You can have a look at regular expression it lets you retrieve the data for specific pattern, in your example it could be a letter E followed with 3 or more numbers.

Comment: If you supporting version >=8.0 than you can use this source code -
    [string containsString:@""]

Comment: Instead of fishing out the ugly numbers from the string, just look for what you want (i.e predefined array). Get individual strings from your predefined array and test with the string input, either with regex or simple NSString API `containsString`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said you want to compare with your existing array element. So you can do the below..

```
NSArray *array = @[@"E100", @"E250", @"E103", @"E200", .....];
NSString *myString = @"Sodium Nitrite E250 is a food additive that gives cured meats, such as ham E103, bacon, hot dogs, frankfurters, smoked fish E1255 corned beef, their characteristic red colour and flavour.";

[array enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *objectString, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    if([myString rangeOfString:objectString].location != NSNotFound) {
        NSLog(@"%@ - found", objectString);
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"%@ - Not found", objectString);
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of extracting that strings from text I would recommend you to find templates from your array like:

```
NSString *input = @"Sodium Nitrite E250 is a food additive ...";
for (NSString *str in @[ @"E100", @"E101", @"E1500" ])
    if ([input rangeOfString:str].location != NSNotFound) {
        // do something
    }
```

Comment: This is is terrible performance-wise if you have large set of strings you are comparing against.

Comment: Thanks, I will try. There is  30-50 words in string.

Comment: @JakubVano without knowing the full task it is hard to recommend high performance solution. It is possible that full architecture of app is not good enough and should be revised. But this code at least will work out of the box

Comment: @Azat I agree that there is not enough information to design an optimal solution, and that OP might not care about the performance. I was just pointing out (maybe not for everyone) obvious drawback for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

try to use this code

```
NSArray *ary = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"E250", nil]; // String Data to find in String
NSMutableArray *aryFoundData = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for (int i=0; i<ary.count; i++) {
    NSString *str = @"Your String E250";
    if ([str containsString:[ary objectAtIndex:i]]) {
        [aryFoundData addObject:[ary objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
}

// Now aryFoundData contains all the data which are available in string
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks! After testing leave a comment here.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this:

```
NSString *testString = @"Sodium Nitrite E250 is a food additive that gives cured meats, such as ham E103, bacon, hot dogs, frankfurters, smoked fish E1255 corned beef, their characteristic red colour and flavour.";

NSRegularExpression *regex = [[NSRegularExpression alloc] initWithPattern:@"E\\d+" options:0 error:nil];

[regex enumerateMatchesInString:testString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, testString.length) usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [testString substringWithRange:result.range]);
}];
```

it logs the following:

*2015-05-05 15:12:55.898 Label[3649:339896] E250*

*2015-05-05 15:12:55.898 Label[3649:339896] E103*

*2015-05-05 15:12:55.898 Label[3649:339896] E1255*

Answer (score 0):

Please try below logic may be your problem solve by this.

```
NSMutableArray *ar = [NSMutableArray new];
NSString *str = @"Sodium Nitrite E250 is a food additive that gives cured meats, such as ham E103, bacon, hot dogs, frankfurters, smoked fish E1255 corned beef, their characteristic red colour and flavour.";

NSArray * words = [str componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
for (NSString * word in words) {
    if ([word length] > 0) {
        NSString * firstLetter = [word substringToIndex:1];
        if ([firstLetter isEqualToString:@"E"]) {
            [ar addObject:word];
        }
    }
}
NSLog(@"%@",ar);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think use "E" letter for key sometime will give mistake in parsing but i will try

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch specific keyword from `NSString` and add them to `NSMutableArray` by doing following things.

```
 NSString* strText = @"Sodium Nitrite E250 is a food additive that gives cured meats, such as ham E103, bacon, hot dogs, frankfurters, smoked fish E1255 corned beef, their characteristic red colour and flavour.";
    __block NSMutableArray* arrayStoreRange = [NSMutableArray new];

    //To Find Image from HTML string and add renge in NSMutableArray
    //width
    NSRegularExpression* tableRegex = [[NSRegularExpression alloc] initWithPattern:@"E\\w*\\d" options:0 error:NULL] ;
    [tableRegex enumerateMatchesInString:strText options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [strText length]) usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *match, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop){

        [arrayStoreRange addObject:[strText substringWithRange:match.range]];

    }];

    NSLog(@"Output : %@",arrayStoreRange);

    for (NSString *str in arrayStoreRange){

        if ([yourArray containsObject:str]) {
            // do something
            NSLog(@"Object found");
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"Object  not found");
        }
    }
```

Output :

```
Output : (
    E250,
    E103,
    E1255
)
```

Hope this help you.